# Add a composite key to the existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a composite key to the existing table but the table already has primary key defined to it. I searched google and cannot seem to find the way to drop it before I create it.

```
ALTER TABLE provider DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(person, place, thing);
```

is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Do you want to replace the primary key, or just add an alternate key, like `alter table provider add unique (person, place, thing);`?

Comment: [Drop a primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: there are two keys already setup for the table

Comment: i want to add another key to be setup as a primary key, i am not a db expert so i do not know if the drop of primary key will create a mess in the db table?

Comment: two keys are setup as PK, Fk and i want the third one to be PK,Fk so i can insert the duplicate if needed

Comment: If you have existing records then dropping a primary key breaks all your foreign key links, so you have to account for that.

Comment: so how can i fix it, what should i do, is there another way of doing it

Comment: No, think about it logically, you have other tables which link to this table using a foreign key relationship based on the OK i.e. if this table PK =1 and the foreign key table foreign key = 1. You want to change both the structure and values, there is no automatic way to do that. You have to remove the foreign key constraints and the primary key constraints, add the new ones, and relink the records. Often you might create a temporary column to allow you to identify the relationships again afterwards.

Comment: But maybe you don't have any tables that reference this one? In which case a simple drop followed by an should be OK - but anything that references these records by ID will need updating.

Comment: A table can have only one primary key. A table can have only one clustered key. The primary key need not be the clustering key, but they generally are one in the same. If you just want an alternate key (one that isn't referenced by FK constraints), just create a new unique index with the compound key. If you really want to CHANGE your primary key, you have to drop the existing (and any FK constraints) and re-create the new one (and re-add your FK constraints).

Comment: with the new compound key, will i be able to insert the duplicates because as of now, the primary key is stopping me